# Running docker gitlab-runner with net=host option

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I've also been having enormous problem setting up docker gitlab-runner containers with net="host" option. Even though in version 1.1 option "docker-network-mode" was introduced I cannot make it work. My config.toml in gitlab-runner container is:

```toml
[[runners]]
    name = "name"
    url = "giturl"
    token = "token"
    executor = "docker"
    [runners.docker]
      tls_verify = false
      image = "maven:3.3.9-jdk-8"
      network_mode = "host"
      privileged = false
      disable_cache = false
      volumes = ["/cache"]
```

and runner does not work with net=host mode. Anyone made it work?

Comment: I've managed to do it with shell register command. Nevertheless I still have a problem, everytime I use net=host on runners while executing build I get ERROR: Build failed: container already exists, which as I read in code means, that HTTP 409 is returned, while sending post request to docker (net=host works with gitlab-runner image itself)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: for people from google: this is the corresponding issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1307

Comment: issue url is now: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1307